# CAD like dimensions in a GLTF model

Tags: 3d, augmented-reality, gltf, cad

Is there a program or plugin that you can add CAD like dimensions to a 3d model and then export it out to GLTF/GLB so the dimensions are displayed?  Currently using Blender but open to other programs as well.